# JavaScript - Canvas snowing animation

Tags: javascript

I want to create a snowing animation effect in JavaScript. My knowledge is really poor in this coding language. However, I managed to do that with one snowflake, with a loop as well.

I now want to generate more than one snowflake. Can someone help me to figure out how to generate more snowflakes?

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById("wip");
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = window.innerWidth-30;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight-30;

let xloc = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.width);
let yloc = 0;
ctx.strokeStyle="#"+((1<<24)*Math.random()|0).toString(16);

function drawflake(){
    ctx.beginPath();

    //Top Right Brunch
    ctx.moveTo(xloc,yloc);
    ctx.lineTo(xloc-7,yloc-7);
    ctx.lineTo(xloc-11,yloc-7);

    ctx.moveTo(xloc-7,yloc-7);
    ctx.lineTo(xloc-7,yloc-11);

    ctx.moveTo(xloc-7,yloc-7);
    ctx.lineTo(xloc-14,yloc-14);
    ctx.lineTo(xloc-17,yloc-14);

    ctx.moveTo(xloc-14,yloc-14);
    ctx.lineTo(xloc-14,yloc-17);

    ctx.moveTo(xloc-14,yloc-14);
    ctx.lineTo(xloc-18,yloc-18);

    //Top Left Brunch
    ctx.moveTo(xloc,yloc);
    ctx.lineTo(xloc+7,yloc-7);
    ctx.lineTo(xloc+11,yloc-7);

    ctx.moveTo(xloc+7,yloc-7);
    ctx.lineTo(xloc+7,yloc-11);

    ctx.moveTo(xloc+7,yloc-7);
    ctx.lineTo(xloc+14,yloc-14);
    ctx.lineTo(xloc+17,yloc-14);

    ctx.moveTo(xloc+14,yloc-14);
    ctx.lineTo(xloc+14,yloc-17);

    ctx.moveTo(xloc+14,yloc-14);
    ctx.lineTo(xloc+18,yloc-18);

    //Bottom Left Brunch
    ctx.moveTo(xloc,yloc);
    ctx.lineTo(xloc+7,yloc+7);
    ctx.lineTo(xloc+7,yloc+11);

    ctx.moveTo(xloc+7,yloc+7);
    ctx.lineTo(xloc+11,yloc+7);

    ctx.moveTo(xloc+7,yloc+7);
    ctx.lineTo(xloc+14,yloc+14);
    ctx.lineTo(xloc+14,yloc+17);

    ctx.moveTo(xloc+14,yloc+14);
    ctx.lineTo(xloc+17,yloc+14);

    ctx.moveTo(xloc+14,yloc+14);
    ctx.lineTo(xloc+18,yloc+18);

    //Bottom Right Brunch
    ctx.moveTo(xloc,yloc);
    ctx.lineTo(xloc-7,yloc+7);
    ctx.lineTo(xloc-11,yloc+7);

    ctx.moveTo(xloc-7,yloc+7);
    ctx.lineTo(xloc-7,yloc+11);

    ctx.moveTo(xloc-7,yloc+7);
    ctx.lineTo(xloc-14,yloc+14);
    ctx.lineTo(xloc-17,yloc+14);

    ctx.moveTo(xloc-14,yloc+14);
    ctx.lineTo(xloc-14,yloc+17);

    ctx.moveTo(xloc-14,yloc+14);
    ctx.lineTo(xloc-18,yloc+18);

    //Left Brunch
    ctx.moveTo(xloc,yloc);
    ctx.lineTo(xloc-9.899,yloc);
    ctx.lineTo(xloc-12.899,yloc-3);

    ctx.moveTo(xloc-9.899,yloc);
    ctx.lineTo(xloc-12.899,yloc+3);

    ctx.moveTo(xloc-9.899,yloc);
    ctx.lineTo(xloc-19.799,yloc);
    ctx.lineTo(xloc-22.799,yloc-3);

    ctx.moveTo(xloc-19.799,yloc);
    ctx.lineTo(xloc-22.799,yloc+3);

    ctx.moveTo(xloc-19.799,yloc);
    ctx.lineTo(xloc-25.456,yloc);

    //Right Brunch
    ctx.moveTo(xloc,yloc);
    ctx.lineTo(xloc+9.899,yloc);
    ctx.lineTo(xloc+12.899,yloc-3);

    ctx.moveTo(xloc+9.899,yloc);
    ctx.lineTo(xloc+12.899,yloc+3);

    ctx.moveTo(xloc+9.899,yloc);
    ctx.lineTo(xloc+19.799,yloc);
    ctx.lineTo(xloc+22.799,yloc-3);

    ctx.moveTo(xloc+19.799,yloc);
    ctx.lineTo(xloc+22.799,yloc+3);

    ctx.moveTo(xloc+19.799,yloc);
    ctx.lineTo(xloc+25.456,yloc);

    ctx.lineWidth = 1;
    ctx.lineCap = 'round';
    ctx.stroke();

    yloc=yloc+1;
    if (yloc>canvas.height) {
        yloc=0;
        xloc = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.width);
        ctx.strokeStyle="#"+((1<<24)*Math.random()|0).toString(16);
    }
}

function clearCanvas() {
    ctx.clearRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

function repeat() {
    clearCanvas();
    drawflake();
    setTimeout(repeat, 24);
}

repeat();
```

```html
<canvas id="wip"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could move all the flake-specific code into a `class` so that you can instantiate a new flake with `new`. The variables that define the properties of the flake should be defined as instance properties. In this case you need to do that change for the variables `xloc`, `yloc` and `strokeStyle`. Even though the latter is a property of `ctx`, that property needs to change every time another flake is displayed, so the flake must know itself what its color is. So that needs to be a property.

Then I would suggest to remove the code that moves the flake back to the top, as that really should be considered a *different* flake. So it makes more sense to destroy the previous instance, and create a new one.

Another asynchronous loop (also with `setTimeout`, but will a larger delay) can take care of creating new flakes.

Here is how your code can be adapted to that. Comments clarify all changes I made:

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById("wip");
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = window.innerWidth-30;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight-30;

class SnowFlake { // each snowflake will be an instance of this class
    constructor() { // this is called when you do `new SnowFlake()`
        // the location is now saved in variables that belong to the instance:
        // Note the use of `this` in all three assignments:
        this.xloc = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.width);
        this.yloc = 0;
        this.strokeStyle="#"+((1<<24)*Math.random()|0).toString(16);
    }
    drawflake(){ // This function becomes a method
        // Get the stroke style that was saved during construction:
        ctx.strokeStyle=this.strokeStyle;
        // Get the location that was saved during construction
        let xloc = this.xloc;
        let yloc = this.yloc;
        
        // No change needed in the drawing part of this function...
        ctx.beginPath();

        //Top Right Brunch
        ctx.moveTo(xloc,yloc);
        ctx.lineTo(xloc-7,yloc-7);
        ctx.lineTo(xloc-11,yloc-7);

        ctx.moveTo(xloc-7,yloc-7);
        ctx.lineTo(xloc-7,yloc-11);

        ctx.moveTo(xloc-7,yloc-7);
        ctx.lineTo(xloc-14,yloc-14);
        ctx.lineTo(xloc-17,yloc-14);

        ctx.moveTo(xloc-14,yloc-14);
        ctx.lineTo(xloc-14,yloc-17);

        ctx.moveTo(xloc-14,yloc-14);
        ctx.lineTo(xloc-18,yloc-18);

        //Top Left Brunch
        ctx.moveTo(xloc,yloc);
        ctx.lineTo(xloc+7,yloc-7);
        ctx.lineTo(xloc+11,yloc-7);

        ctx.moveTo(xloc+7,yloc-7);
        ctx.lineTo(xloc+7,yloc-11);

        ctx.moveTo(xloc+7,yloc-7);
        ctx.lineTo(xloc+14,yloc-14);
        ctx.lineTo(xloc+17,yloc-14);

        ctx.moveTo(xloc+14,yloc-14);
        ctx.lineTo(xloc+14,yloc-17);

        ctx.moveTo(xloc+14,yloc-14);
        ctx.lineTo(xloc+18,yloc-18);

        //Bottom Left Brunch
        ctx.moveTo(xloc,yloc);
        ctx.lineTo(xloc+7,yloc+7);
        ctx.lineTo(xloc+7,yloc+11);

        ctx.moveTo(xloc+7,yloc+7);
        ctx.lineTo(xloc+11,yloc+7);

        ctx.moveTo(xloc+7,yloc+7);
        ctx.lineTo(xloc+14,yloc+14);
        ctx.lineTo(xloc+14,yloc+17);

        ctx.moveTo(xloc+14,yloc+14);
        ctx.lineTo(xloc+17,yloc+14);

        ctx.moveTo(xloc+14,yloc+14);
        ctx.lineTo(xloc+18,yloc+18);

        //Bottom Right Brunch
        ctx.moveTo(xloc,yloc);
        ctx.lineTo(xloc-7,yloc+7);
        ctx.lineTo(xloc-11,yloc+7);

        ctx.moveTo(xloc-7,yloc+7);
        ctx.lineTo(xloc-7,yloc+11);

        ctx.moveTo(xloc-7,yloc+7);
        ctx.lineTo(xloc-14,yloc+14);
        ctx.lineTo(xloc-17,yloc+14);

        ctx.moveTo(xloc-14,yloc+14);
        ctx.lineTo(xloc-14,yloc+17);

        ctx.moveTo(xloc-14,yloc+14);
        ctx.lineTo(xloc-18,yloc+18);

        //Left Brunch
        ctx.moveTo(xloc,yloc);
        ctx.lineTo(xloc-9.899,yloc);
        ctx.lineTo(xloc-12.899,yloc-3);

        ctx.moveTo(xloc-9.899,yloc);
        ctx.lineTo(xloc-12.899,yloc+3);

        ctx.moveTo(xloc-9.899,yloc);
        ctx.lineTo(xloc-19.799,yloc);
        ctx.lineTo(xloc-22.799,yloc-3);

        ctx.moveTo(xloc-19.799,yloc);
        ctx.lineTo(xloc-22.799,yloc+3);

        ctx.moveTo(xloc-19.799,yloc);
        ctx.lineTo(xloc-25.456,yloc);

        //Right Brunch
        ctx.moveTo(xloc,yloc);
        ctx.lineTo(xloc+9.899,yloc);
        ctx.lineTo(xloc+12.899,yloc-3);

        ctx.moveTo(xloc+9.899,yloc);
        ctx.lineTo(xloc+12.899,yloc+3);

        ctx.moveTo(xloc+9.899,yloc);
        ctx.lineTo(xloc+19.799,yloc);
        ctx.lineTo(xloc+22.799,yloc-3);

        ctx.moveTo(xloc+19.799,yloc);
        ctx.lineTo(xloc+22.799,yloc+3);

        ctx.moveTo(xloc+19.799,yloc);
        ctx.lineTo(xloc+25.456,yloc);

        ctx.lineWidth = 1;
        ctx.lineCap = 'round';
        ctx.stroke();

        // Save the new location to the instance:
        this.yloc = yloc+1;
        // Don't deal here with the range check. Do that in `repeat`
    }
}

function clearCanvas() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}

// Collection that holds all of the active flakes
let flakes = new Set;

function repeat() {
    clearCanvas();
    // Draw all flakes
    for (let flake of flakes) {
        flake.drawflake();
        if (flake.yloc > canvas.height) { // flake reached the bottom?
            flakes.delete(flake); // remove the flake from the collection
        }
    }
    setTimeout(repeat, 24);
}

// new function to deal with the generation of new flakes
function generate() {
    flakes.add(new SnowFlake()); // construct a new flake and add it to the collection
    // Make the time between two generations of a new flakes a bit random
    setTimeout(generate, 1000 + Math.random() * 2000);
}

generate(); // also start the generations
repeat();
```

```html
<canvas id="wip"></canvas>
```

You can influence the rate of flake generation, and its variation, by changing the two constants used in the expression `1000 + Math.random() * 2000`.

Answer (score 0):

I would image that you would use [Classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) to create multiple snow flakes who have the same behavior but with unique properties. Behavior like your `drawflake` function which draws the line of each flake.

Create a `class` that is a blueprint to all future `SnowFlakes` and it give it the method `draw` in which you will put your drawing logic.

```
const canvas = document.getElementById("wip");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = window.innerWidth-30;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight-30;

class SnowFlake {
  constructor(context) {
    this.ctx = context;
  }
  draw() {
    this.ctx.beginPath();
    // other drawing functions...
  }
}
```

Now you can start creating `SnowFlake` *instances*, as many as you would like. Write a function which will create instances of the newly created `class` and make it able to pass the `amount` of instances and the `context` of the canvas. The `amount` parameter will be *how many* instances you want to create and have returned, and the `context` is the context of the `canvas` element which will be passed into the object to use it inside of it.

```
function createSnowFlakes(amount, context) {
    const snowFlakes = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
        const snowFlake = new SnowFlake(context);
        snowFlakes.push(snowFlake);
    }
    return snowFlakes;
}
```

Now create the instances by calling your `createSnowFlakes` function with the `amount` and `context` parameter given and store the result in a variable.

```
const amountOfSnowFlakes = 10;
const snowFlakes = createSnowFlakes(amountOfSnowFlakes, ctx)
```

You have now created multiple `SnowFlake` instances and each and everyone of them can draw itself whenever and wherever. All you have to do is call the `.draw()` method of each `SnowFlake`, which is your drawing logic which you will add yourself.

Create a function that loops over each `SnowFlake` and calls the `.draw()` method. With this function you can control when all the snow flakes have to be drawn and can be used in your `repeat` function.

```
function drawSnowFlakes(snowFlakes) {
    snowFlakes.forEach(snowFlake => snowFlake.draw());
}
```

By now you should have a lot of control over creating a group of snow flakes en when to draw them. Go from here and see if it works out.

And don't hesitate to ask a question.